# I don’t want to View Photos or Listen to Music from the Dash, how can I change them to something I will use?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash

The View Photos and Listen to Music shortcuts in the Unity Dash are useless to me because I have my photo and music directories organized and I just browse to the what I want to see / hear and open the files from there.  I really would like have Eclipse and Pidgin easily accessible, but not necessarily in the Launcher if I’m not running them.  I can’t find any settings for what shows up there, and all the searches I’ve done just bring me to people asking about how to change the default program for photos.  I’m fine with doing something like editing a config file to get what I want if there’s no settings GUI — I just don’t know where to look.

Comment: That question is similar, and I found it when looking for information that would answer my question and thought it looked promising by the title, but it didn’t help.  The difference is that I want a completely different type of application while the other question seems more about how to set a different program for check email / view photos.  I don’t want to view photos; I want to write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in 11.04.

Right now the categories on the first row are hardcoded and the 2nd row is hard coded to the browser, photo app, mail, and music player that the user has set.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently still the case in 11.10.

The shortcuts "Browse the Web" and "Listen to Music" respond to the settings found in the application "System-info" under the "Default Applications" tab.

However, "View Photos" does not.

Additionally, you cannot edit the options shown under "Default Applications", so you can't, for example have "View Photos" open Picasa.

I wish this was fixed, as I'm setting up the computer for a non technical user who relies on picasa and webmail, and they won't understand the fact that the links on the unity dashboard take them to the wrong place.

Comment: i was hoping for 11.10 to bring more customizability to the dash, but it instead seems to have taken away customizability from other areas.  i have some notes from how i got gmail in as the check email link that you might be able to use to do something similar with picasa:  http://wiki.track7.org/User:Misterhaan/Linux_Client_Setup#set_gmail_as_preferred_mail_program